# Change reply-to email address to specific WooCommerce email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, header, email-notifications

I'm trying to add a different reply-to email to the notification sent to the customer when a note is added to the order.
So far I have:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'add_replyto_emails_header', 10, 4 );
function add_replyto_emails_header( $headers, $email_id) {
    $replyto_email = 'store_owner@gmail.com';
    
$email_status = array( 'wc_email_customer_note',  'customer_note');
    if ( in_array( $email_id,  $email_status))  {
        $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $replyto_email . "\r\n";
    }

    error_log( print_r( $headers, true ) );
    return $headers;
}
```

The email is sent, but the header is not modified. I'm guessing that the status in the email_status array is not correct and I can't find any other references to the id of this email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look to [`WC_Email` `get_headers()` method source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.9.2/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php#L405-L422), you will see that **for all notifications send to the customer** *(so 'customer_note' email notification too)*, you get [this related line code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.9.2/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php#L415):

```
$header .= 'Reply-to: ' . $this->get_from_name() . ' <' . $this->get_from_address() . ">\r\n";
```

Now for `WC_Email` [`get_from_name()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.9.2/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php#L620) and [`get_from_address()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.9.2/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php#L631), there are an available filter hook foreach one that you can use to change the reply to name and email address, so try instead:

```
// Change reply to name
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_from_name', 'change_reply_to_name', 10, 2 );
function change_reply_to_name( $from_name, $wc_email ){
    if( 'customer_note' === $wc_email->id ) {
        $from_name = ''; // Empty name
    }
    return $from_name;
}

// Change reply to adress
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_from_address', 'change_reply_to_address', 10, 2 ); 
function change_reply_to_address( $from_email, $wc_email ){
    if( 'customer_note' === $wc_email->id ) {
        $from_email = 'store_owner@gmail.com';
    }
    return $from_email;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Does this change the "From Email" or the Reply-To? We want to maintain the original "From Email" from WC settings, but want a different Reply-To email.